# Оптимизация в Unity3D: static

Tags: android, unity3d

Доброго времени суток. Подскажите, в чем заключается работа галочки **static** в окне инспектора Unity3D?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько мне известно ей помечаются объекты, которые не будут перемещаться в сцене (например деревья) для оптимизации прорисовки таких статик-объектов как единое целое, их теней и тп.

Но я работаю над 2D играми под Android платформу и возникает вопрос: есть ли смысл использовать эту галочку для неперемещаемых объектов в 2D играх?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static включает в себе много действий батчинг статический, навигация по навмешу, запекание света и т.д. Каждое действие можно выставить вручную. Если тебе ничего из этого не нужно, то статик тебе не нужен. Еще самое важное статический батчинг хоть и экономит кол-во drawcall, но жрет место , в твоем случае, в .apk